# Highchart treemap is not showing numeric data in name field

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, highcharts

I'm new to High charts. I'm facing an issue while putting the numeric data in the name field, the data is not getting displayed over the chart.

Here's the working demo => [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/subhojit/cxz5y3ho/)

Here's the code =>

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
    colorAxis: {
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'treemap',
        layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
        data: [{
            name: 2011,
            value: 6,
            colorValue: 1
        }, {
            name: 2012,
            value: 6,
            colorValue: 2
        }, {
            name: 2013,
            value: 4,
            colorValue: 3
        }, {
            name: 2014,
            value: 3,
            colorValue: 4
        }, {
            name: 2015,
            value: 2,
            colorValue: 5
        }, {
            name: 2016,
            value: 2,
            colorValue: 6
        }, {
            name: 2017,
            value: 1,
            colorValue: 7
        }]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Treemap'
    }
});
```

Any help regarding the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: numeric won't support for name. It should be string. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.name

Comment: If I'm putting Year in place of name and using numeric, its not working. Is there any way to show numeric to show data over the chart? @UKS

Comment: you have to change that to string

Comment: As the other users mentioned - the name cannot be a number format, it should be a string. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vk75ed41/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name field is a string so if you want to display a numeric data on the chart you have to convert it into a string.
To do so you can simply add quotes :

```
name: '2011',
```

Or you can use the toString() method:

```
name: numericValue.toString(),
```

See demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/twykh4s5/)